# What is the likely cause of the error `The program could not deserialize the given instruction`

Tags: anchor, error

I ran into this error message when running a transaction, any idea what could be going wrong?

```
errorLogs: [
    'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.'
  ],
  logs: [
    'Program BH8xjXWTRn78CRmFnNwf8uG6DpVeAu5tRhbXWqVmQuFR invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: Initialize',
    'Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: InstructionDidNotDeserialize. Error Number: 102. Error Message: The program could not deserialize the given instruction.',
    'Program BH8xjXWTRn78CRmFnNwf8uG6DpVeAu5tRhbXWqVmQuFR consumed 3688 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program BH8xjXWTRn78CRmFnNwf8uG6DpVeAu5tRhbXWqVmQuFR failed: custom program error: 0x66'
  ],
  error: {
    errorCode: { code: 'InstructionDidNotDeserialize', number: 102 },
    errorMessage: 'The program could not deserialize the given instruction',
    comparedValues: undefined,
    origin: undefined
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem that you are addressing is related to

> passing incorrectly serialized instruction data to the program

as [@Henry](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/255/henry-e) said above, but in my case, I had this issue with the `#[instruction(...)]` which was coming from the fact that I was not using the arguments in the correct order as explained in the documentation:

> You can access the instruction's arguments with the
> `#[instruction(..)]` attribute. You have to list them
> in the same order as in the instruction but you can
> omit all arguments after the last one you need.

Answer (score 3):

Typically this error is because the IDL or client-gen code is out of date and the code is passing incorrectly serialized instruction data to the program.